# Using Dispatcher to force UI thread to update a control when UI is current on Task.Wait();

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

Is it possible to force the UI thread, to stop waiting for the task(s) to finish, update a UI control via Dispatcher, and then have the UI revert back to waiting for the task(s) to complete?

Ive just tried the following code, but its not working as it appears the

```
UpdatePB(int NewValue)
```

method is being executed by the non UI thread.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace UpdateControlViaDispatcherUITaskWaitAll
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void UpdatePB(int NewValue)
        {
            pb1.Value = NewValue;
        }


        private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Task tk = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Worker();
            });
            tk.Wait();
        }

        public void Worker()
        {
            int currentValue = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                currentValue = i;

                Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    UpdatePB(currentValue);
                }));


                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you sleeping for 1 second?

Comment: Right. You shouldn't consider the UI thread as waiting for tasks to finish, you should consider it as busy. It just happens to be busy sleeping. :) From the perspective of your task, that's the same thing as a something that *you* would classify as "busy". Make sure the UI thread isn't busy. It shouldn't be.

Comment: DanielKelley: Just so i could see a clear gap when stepping through the code.
@hvd So basically its not possible then without creating another thread first, which would then wait for all subsequent tasks to finish?

Comment: I'm confused, I thought `Dispatcher` was used by WPF, not Winforms. It works with Winforms too?

Comment: Application.Current.Dispatcher isn't used by winforms. In winforms the dispatcher is reachable on any UI element.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid blocking the UI thread:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Task.Factory
        .StartNew(this.Worker)
        .ContinueWith(this.OnWorkerCompleted);
}

public void Worker()
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        btn1.IsEnabled = false;
    }));
    // your stuff here...
}

private void OnWorkerCompleted(Task obj)
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        btn1.IsEnabled = true;
    }));
}
```

Try to minimize calls to Dispatcher and also try using BackgroundWorker which supports automatic syncronization between background thread and UI thread with ProgressChanged and RunWorkerComplete events.

Answer (score 0):

`WPF Dispatcher` has task queue of `DispatcherOperation`, so when you call `tk.Wait();` it blocks Dispatcher thread until `tk` finishes. You haven't ability to pause this waiting and resume again, but only cancel `DispatcherOperation`. But in your case I assume you better disable button (or whole window) and enable it when `tk` finishes. So you should consider asynchronous waiting for `tk` to complete.